# Nova list fields

Tags: openstack

Is there any way to find the possible fields for the `nova show --fields` command? Currently I can fill the `--fields` parameter with anything and it never complains, just fails silently.

The docs say use the `show` command, but that reports a machines characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nova show returns may different from version to version, here is an example:

```
$ nova show b3cdc6c0-85a7-4904-ae85-71918f734048
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Property                            | Value                               |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state               | scheduling                          |
| image                               | cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-uec             |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                 | building                            |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name       | instance-00000002                   |
| flavor                              | m1.small                            |
| id                                  | b3cdc6c0-85a7-4904-ae85-71918f734048|
| security_groups                     | [{u'name': u'default'}]             |
| user_id                             | 376744b5910b4b4da7d8e6cb483b06a8    |
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                   | MANUAL                              |
| accessIPv4                          |                                     |
| accessIPv6                          |                                     |
| progress                            | 0                                   |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state              | 0                                   |
| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone         | nova                                |
| config_drive                        |                                     |
| status                              | BUILD                               |
| updated                             | 2013-07-16T16:25:34Z                |
| hostId                              |                                     |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                | None                                |
| key_name                            | KeyPair01                           |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname | None                                |
| name                                | myCirrosServer                      |
| adminPass                           | tVs5pL8HcPGw                        |
| tenant_id                           | 66265572db174a7aa66eba661f58eb9e    |
| created                             | 2013-07-16T16:25:34Z                |
| metadata                            | {u'KEY': u'VALUE'}                  |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

The property column is all the fields available to specify to --fields